# Getting delimited substrings using sed+regexp

Tags: regex, sed, substring

I'm trying to get substrings using sed with regexp. I want to get the first and second "fields" delimited by ":".

To get the first field I used the following command, but don't know how to get the second field.

Command used to get the first field:

```
sed -r -n '1,2 s/([^:]+).*/\1/p' /etc/passwd
```

Input file (example):

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash   
daemon:x:1:1:daemon:/usr/sbin:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

Command's result:

```
root   
daemon
```

But I tried do get the first ("root") and second ("x") fields (examples based on the file's first line only), but I did't succedded.

I tried:

```
sed -r -n '1,2 s/([^:]+).*([^:]+).*/\1 \2/p' /etc/passwd
```

Command's result:

```
root h   
daemon n
```

Desired result:

```
root x   
daemon x
```

Comment: With awk: `awk -F ':' '{print $1,$2}' file`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sed` uses [greedy match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions). In

```
sed -r -n '1,2 s/([^:]+).*([^:]+).*/\1 \2/p' /etc/passwd
                        ^^
```

`.*` matches as many characters as possible. You need

```
sed -r -n '1,2 s/([^:]+):([^:]+).*/\1 \2/p' /etc/passwd
                        ^
```

**Demo**: http://ideone.com/wjL7Za.

By the way, a simpler way to do this is using `cut`:

```
cut -d ":" -f 1,2 --output-delimiter=' ' /etc/passwd
```

**Demo**: http://ideone.com/stJdSy.

Comment: Fantastic! Great explanation. And the websites' links are amazing. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Another expression that would return the desire result would be:

```
([a-z]+):([a-z]+).*
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/TjSnSW/1/)

---

```
sed -r -n '1,2 s/([^:]+):([^:]+).*/\1 \2/p'
```

#### [Sed Demo](http://ideone.com/Hcnc4Y)